# Comparing two values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named A, which contains thousands of records.
It has columns `name`, `copy` and `id`.

I am plotting a graph using the data from this table.

The data is a comparison between two names (Raju and Ramu) and their copies.
I was trying for an SQl code, which will display my data as

```
------------------------------------------------------
Copy         Raju(no.of copies)      Ramu(no.of copies)
-------------------------------------------------------
Harrypotter         7                       8

Prince of Persia    12              6

....


....
```

How can I do that in mysql? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: could at lease show us the table, and what you mean 2 names Raju and Ramu is it some value in 1 column?

Comment: I guess you'll need a GROUP BY, with COUNT.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you ask a question here.. It's very hard to understand what do you want to achieve.. you should give us table's structure , input and the desired output and that way we can understand your question.

[This is how you ask a proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Anyway, if I understood correctly, this is what you need:

```
SELECT Copy,
       sum(case when name = 'Raju' then 1 else 0 end) as Raju_Copies,
       sum(case when name = 'Ramu' then 1 else 0 end) as Ramu_Copies,
FROM A
GROUP BY Copy
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the COUNT() function of mysql and GROUP BY statement.